# Laravel 4: How do I create a non-primary auto incrementing column with migrations?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently working on a Laravel 4 project consisting of a master server and many clients. The clients create data and send this to the master server. To avoid conflicts I am using UUID v4 as the primary key.

However, once the data is created on the server I want to assign a unique auto-incrementing integer so it is easier for users to identify the data. For example: Instead of speaking about `item 5a8e896d-3ab4-48d2-9d39-faeb5227f012` a user can speak about `item #24567`

To keep my app managable I am using migrations, my current migration for this table looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('items', function($table)
    {
        $table->create();
        $table->string('id')->primary(); //'id' For the purpose of keeping the ORM working, this field stores the UUID.
        $table->integer('number', true); //The human readable item number, the second parameter is true for auto-increment
        $table->text('otherdata');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The problem is that Laravel automagically creates a primary key when defining auto-increment and so the migration ends up failing because there are two primary keys.

```
[Exception] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined
  (SQL: alter table `items` add primary key items_id_primary(`id`)) (Bindings: array ())
```

Is there any way to have a table with a primary key and a seperate auto-incrementing field using Laravel 4 migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, Laravel seems to be creating a primary key for each auto_increment field. WHen i removed the `primary key` part it asked me to provide an index so I calling `->unique()` on the migration, but this too did not work. Changing the `return ' auto_increment primary key';` to `return ' auto_increment unique'`; solved my problem, although it is now hacked in the core, which of course is bad practice.

```
/**
 * Get the SQL for an auto-increment column modifier.
 *
 * @param  Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint  $blueprint
 * @param  Illuminate\Support\Fluent  $column
 * @return string|null
 */
protected function modifyIncrement(Blueprint $blueprint, Fluent $column)
{
    if ($column->type == 'integer' and $column->autoIncrement)
    {
        return ' auto_increment unique'; //return ' auto_increment primary key';
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think so this is the better solution(to change in core functionality of laravel Db class.).

Comment: If you would have read my comment you would have understood your solution did not answer my question. This is why I downvoted it. I know my solution is not best practice, but yours does not solve my problem.

Comment: so u need two separate column one is auto incremented primary key and another key for uuid. am i right?

Comment: The UUID is a primary key and the other column has to be unique and auto incrementing, correct. But, it was about a migration that did not work, which has nothing to do with the ORM.

Comment: You forgot to specify which file was that you modified.
Also, you could extend that class and update the Façade to avoid hardcoding into the core…

Comment: Edited File: Laravel Project ▸ vendor ▸ laravel ▸ framework ▸ src ▸ Illuminate ▸ Database ▸ Schema ▸ Grammars -> MySqlGrammar.php

Answer (score 1):

trick is to add it outside of the Schema::create like this

```
Schema::create('payments', function(Blueprint $table)
{
   $table->string('primaryKey', 30);
   $table->primary('primaryKey');
   //...
});
DB::statement('ALTER Table tableName add id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT;');
```

Then redo migrations, the key will create with name id in the table tableName then you can access it like any other key.

Answer (score -1):

I think it cannot be done without modifying the core files, because creating a auto_ increment automatically makes it as a primary key.

Better if u can report it as bug in Larvel framework dev. team.

[here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues)
Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

yes you can do it in your Model declaration of your Items class

```
class Items extends Eloquent {
   /**
 * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = false;

}
```

now your primary key is no more auto incremented field.

Comment: In my question I stated I needed one incrementing (non-primary) and one primary key, however Laravel seems to be creating a second primary key when I mark a column as auto-incrementing. How would disabling auto increment in the model (i'm speaking about migrations) change this behaviour?

Comment: This is just the opposite of what he asked.